# Laravel sets Authorization Bearer header empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I'm using Laravel Passport to authenticate users with JWT tokens. I send the tokens to the frontend via cookies.

I have a middleware that takes the value of the cookie and set it in the authorization header.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        if ($request->cookie('accessToken')) {
            $request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $request->cookie('accessToken'));
        }
    
        $this->authenticate($request, $guards);
    
        return $next($request);
    }

    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('weblogin');
        }
    }
}
```

But when i visit a protected route, it throws an Authentication Exception.

If I dump the headers in the Handler.php it returns that the authorization header is empty.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        GeneralException::class,
    ];


    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
            //
        });
    }

    /**
     * Sobreescritura del mensaje de error de autenticacion
     */
    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        $message = __('messages.passport.unauthenticated');
        $r_code = 1;

        dd($request->header()); // this returns ['authorization' => ""]
        
        return $request->expectsJson()
                    ? json_response($r_code, $message, null, 401)
                    : redirect()->guest(route('weblogin'));
    }
}
```

But this only happens if the Authorization header is Bearer, if for example I set in the middleware the header to Authorization Something xxx, that value is returned correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried it with back-qoute like this?

```
$request->headers->set('Authorization', `Bearer $request->cookie('accessToken')`);
```

Comment: I ended up deleting the vendor folder and reinstalling everything againg, and it got fixed. Weird stuff.